# How to get the id of specific field in tabel asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

So i have a transaction table that contains only the transactions that haven't been confirmed yet.
it contains the transaction number (PK), the transaction status which is pending, and the confirmation (which is a button for uplouding a picture of the accomplished transaction). what i need is, if the user uplouded the picture, the tranaction status will change to accomplished according to which tranasction the user chose.

I do not know how to connect the uploud pic button with the transaction number. I tried to connect them by the id and retrieve the id but it didn't work. i did 4 choices of tags (, ,  and asp:Button) and tried to retrieve it with request.form("name") just to test if its retrieve something, but it returns nothing.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a single button separate from the table, or a button for each row in the table?

If there is a button in each row, then assign the transaction ID to the Button as a CommandArgument. Assuming you load the table from a database, it could look something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="ConfirmTransaction" runat="server" CommandArgumant='<%#Eval("TransactionNumber")%>' OnClick="UploadPicture" />
```

Then you can retrive the CommandArgument of the button in the OnClick event and use it in your update statement.

But as said above, you could post a snippet of how your table and buttons look like, as without seeing it it's hard to give a proper answer.